# Low temperature curing process?

Tags: paint, ca2216243a1

In reference to the patent: [CA2216243A1](https://www.google.com/patents/CA2216243A1)

I am an artist, not a specialist. I recreated the formula of the patent in my studio and applied it onto glass with an airbrush, and it seems to work perfectly when cured at about 200°C for 20 minutes in a kitchen oven, with the grill switched ON. However, the author of the patent says that this paint can be cured at low temperature, between 100° and 200°C, or even lower.

I noticed that when the layer of potassium silicate paint is not properly dried, it tends to attract humidity and becomes soft again after a few days in a humid environment. My problem is that I want to work on large glass sheets that are already in place in a building, and I dont have the budget to unmount them, transport them to a company that has an oven, etc.

I came up with a few ideas, would you help me figure out if these ideas are realistic?

If I work in summer (the work is in Rome, Italy), the temperature is between 18 and 28°C and there's a lot of sun, long days, so it could help the drying process (but humidity is always around 80%). But would it be enough?

Could I "seal" the as-dry-as-possible coatings with a waterproof mixture of Syton X30 (link: https://www.kremer-pigmente.com/media/pdf/31430e.pdf) and acrylic medium

I read that treatment with chemical setting agents could cure potassium silicate (link: www.pqcorp.com/docs/default-source/recommended-literature/pq-corporation/potassium-silicates/bulletin_12-31.pdf)

Any other suggestions on how to cure such a coating at low temperature?

Comment: this question is not on topic here. Please read [about] and [ask] for more info on what questions are on topic. Thanks.

Comment: Ok sorry I didn't get it, thanks for the information